# Why are jQuery objects in property initialization empty?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```
'use strict';
var Controller = function Controller() {};

Controller.init = function() {
  if (!Controller.PROPERTIE.element || !Controller.PROPERTIE.indicator) {
    return 'Expected to find [data-controller] and [data-controller-to]';
  }

  Controller._start();
};

Controller.PROPERTIE = {
  element: $('[data-controller]'),
  indicator: $('[data-controller-to]'),
  state: false
};

Controller._start = function() {
  Controller.PROPERTIE.indicator.bind('click', Controller._toggle);
};

Controller._toggle = function() {
  Controller.PROPERTIE.element
    .animate({
      bottom: (Controller.PROPERTIE.state = !Controller.PROPERTIE.state) ? '-110' : '0'
    });
};
```

apparently the elements in the object property does not exist, but they do exist ! Could someone tell me if I can not use javascript like that?

Maybe there is something with hoisting that is breaking the script?

I already try put the object before the init and the result is the same.

I know that i can extend prototype, but i have my reasons to use like this.

Thanks.

Comment: is `$()` jQuery? Do they reference DOM elements? Have they been loaded yet?

Comment: Yes, $ is jQuery, they reference DOM elements they exists, if i try to get them inside with jQuery i can, but if i try to get the reference i can't

Comment: It is not clear what order you execute the code in or what property you are asking about.  Please clarify exactly which property you are having an issue with ("object property" is a generic term - it does not describe which property you mean) and show the calling code.

Comment: sorry... i mean the elements inside the object Controller.PROPERTIE, they doesn't exist in my code, but they exist in the DOM. I'm trying to test both, element and indicator..

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, the question is... do the DOM elements exist before setting up `Controller.PROPERTIE`? (If no dynamic shenanigans, then they should be ready after jQuery ready event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three possible causes:

1. The code is being initialized before the DOM has been parsed.
2. Your HTML does not actually contain elements that will match these selectors.
3. The desired elements are being created dynamically after this code is being initialized.

In this declaration:

```
Controller.PROPERTIE = {
  element: $('[data-controller]'),
  indicator: $('[data-controller-to]'),
  state: false
};
```

the two jQuery expressions will be evaluated immediately as this code is parsed.  If this code is not placed at the very end of the body, then those elements will likely not exist yet.

The usual solution to this is to not initialize those elements in a static declaration, but to initialize them by calling a function after the page has been loaded.

If you really intend for them to be globals, then you could just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Controller.PROPERTIE = {
      element: $('[data-controller]'),
      indicator: $('[data-controller-to]'),
      state: false
    };
});
```

But, you will also have to make sure that you don't try to use them until after this code runs.

---

The only other possible cause I can think of is that your DOM does not contain elements that match your two selectors.  It seems like it's likely one of these two issues.  Since you haven't shown us either the overall page structure of the HTML you intend to match, it's impossible for us to anything other than tell you what causes it might be.

Comment: This code is being execute after dom loads @jfriend00

Comment: @AmandaFerrari - well, you're either mistaken about when the code relative to the DOM loading or your DOM doesn't contain elements that match these selectors.  It's one of those.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari - I summarized the possible causes in my answer.  The ball is in your court to either investigate these issues or show us more of the full context that the problem occurs in.

Comment: Well, i try to use document.ready in other file that i was requiring this file with browserify, it works.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are thinking the jQuery object is not defined because of this:

```
if (!Controller.PROPERTIE.element || !Controller.PROPERTIE.indicator) {
    return 'Expected to find [data-controller] and [data-controller-to]';
  }
```

You must remember that jQuery constructor `$()` will always return an object. If you really want to test if there's a selected item you must use the length property of the jQuery object.

```
if (!Controller.PROPERTIE.element.length || !Controller.PROPERTIE.indicator.length) {
    //element or indicator not there.
    return 'Expected to find [data-controller] and [data-controller-to]';
  }
```